# How to access all the values of a specific key of different dictionnaries in a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandasSeries variable which is made up of different dictionnay. They are two specific keys which I want to retrieve  the data in a column of a dataFrame.

When I print the pandasSeries, it looks like this : input_ids and attention mask are key for each dictionnary in the Series

```
path_to_lge = "flaubert/flaubert_small_cased"
flaubert_tokenizer = FlaubertTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_to_lge, do_lowercase=False)

#texte is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

encoding = texte.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode_plus(x, add_special_tokens=True, return_token_type_ids=False, truncation=True, padding=True, return_attention_mask=True)))

print(type(encoding)) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(encoding)

0     [input_ids, attention_mask]
1     [input_ids, attention_mask]
2     [input_ids, attention_mask]
3     [input_ids, attention_mask]
4     [input_ids, attention_mask]
5     [input_ids, attention_mask]
6     [input_ids, attention_mask]
7     [input_ids, attention_mask]
8     [input_ids, attention_mask]
9     [input_ids, attention_mask]
```

If I want to print an element of the enconding variable , it look like this:

```
print(encoding[0])

{'input_ids': [0, 93, 106, 97, 26, 578, 14, 535, 61, 6823, 21, 7652, 19, 151, 11804, 1934, 75, 20340, 75, 10777                                          , 1006, 2986, 15, 200, 75, 50, 1779, 8475, 58, 15, 200, 24023, 14, 50, 75, 25601, 14, 50, 45, 32, 56, 2572, 16,                                           107, 56, 528, 23, 24023, 16, 133, 242, 43, 1291, 14, 63, 535, 61, 20, 6823, 19, 151, 32897, 5589, 659, 386, 87                                          , 3167, 19, 151, 15469, 1271, 23579, 742, 11707, 15, 200, 10500, 9663, 87, 21020, 16, 113, 27, 597, 14, 21, 112                                          0, 16, 175, 20, 4146, 51, 27, 42, 1391, 14, 157, 48, 2158, 19, 245, 16, 33897, 75, 1846, 75, 113, 27, 157, 16,                                           2175, 14, 79, 27, 597, 18, 157, 14, 45, 52, 23, 536, 32, 61, 51, 97, 42, 462, 33, 17, 2038, 16, 1], 'attention_                                          mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1                                          , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1                                          , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1                                          , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

I want to retrieve in a form of dataframe each value of inputs_ids and attention_mask in a dataFrame like this :

So what I expect :

```
input_ids                      attention_mask
[0, 16, 175, 20, 4146, ...]    [1,1,1,1,1,...]
[51, 27, 42, 1391, 14,...]     [1,1,1,1,1...]
[157, 48, 2158, 19, 245,...]   [1,1,1,1,1,..]
```

I try to get the value all element in dataseries by doing this below , But I get errors , I also did this but same , all my tentatives failes , If someone could help me thank family :
:

```
encoding_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['input_ids', 'attention_mask'])
for e in encoding:
   encoding_df.append(e['input_ids'], e['attention_mask'])

print(encoding_df)
```

Error I get :  Empty DataFrame
Columns: [input_ids, attention_mask]
Index: []